# How to compare two columns by ignoring special charactes?

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, where-clause

I am comparing two columns from different tables to get the matching records. Those tables do not have any unique key other than first and last names. But I don't get the correct output if tableA has `Aa'aa` and tableB has `Aaaa`. Could any one advise how to compare by ignoring the special characters / any other alternate solution to get them matched?

```
   SELECT * FROM TableA  A where EXISTS
    (SELECT '' FROM TableB B
                WHERE 
                TRIM(A.namef) = TRIM(B.namef)
                AND TRIM(A.namel) = TRIM(B.namel)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a regex approach. Assuming that you want to compare only the alphabetic and numeric characters, you can do:

```
where 
        regexp_replace(a.namef, '\W', '', 'g') = regexp_replace(b.namef, '\W', '', 'g')
    and regexp_replace(a.namel, '\W', '', 'g') = regexp_replace(b.namel, '\W', '', 'g')
```

Basically this removes non-word characters from each string before comparing them - with a word character being defined as a letter or a digit, plus the underscore character.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove anything that is not a letter, use:

```
regexp_replace(a.namef, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'g') = regexp_replace(b.namef, '[^A-Za-z]', '', 'g')
```

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your time and response. But this completely ignores everything that is not a letter. But I can use this for another purpose.